# Construct HXT arrow that selects multiple Maybe values

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm confused with HXT arrows API. Similarly to the list monad, any arrow that produces no result will determine result of `[]` and match will become element in one dimension of Cartesian product of all matches.

I have XML file with a nested optional elements like this:

```
<root>
 ...
 <b>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
  ...
 </b>
 <x>3</x>
 <y>4</y>
 ...
</root>
```

How can I construct an arrow that will traverse this tree once and produce result in fixed structure similar to one below? I care only about small part of the structure.

```
[(Just 1, Just 2), (Just 3, Just 4)] :: [(Maybe a, Maybe b), (Maybe a, Maybe b)]
```

or

```
[(Nothing, Nothing), (Just 3, Just 4)] :: [(Maybe a, Maybe b), (Maybe a, Maybe b)]
```

Comment: I tried to use arrows of the form `type Zip a b = Kleisli (MaybeT Stream) a b` [infinite streams of maybe-values; see Control.Arrow, Control.Monad, and Data.Stream] to create a ZipList monad which was "lifted" into an HXT arrow. It takes a bit of work. The result does indeed get `&&&` right but I wasn't able to get HXT's `deep` to work properly; `xread >>> deep (hasName "a") &&& deep (hasName "b")` failed when it searched for `b` elements.  In general ZipLists do what you want but fail to have the `ArrowApply` instance which `ArrowList` needs. Not sure why the HXT API is so complex.